# Custom RecyclerAdapter and startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, onactivityresult

I have a `Fragment` that contains a `RecyclerView` which uses a custom `RecyclerAdapter`. I have an `onClickListener` inside my custom `RecyclerAdapter` - when a position is clicked I want it to start `startActivityForResult`.  So far this works in as such as when it is clicked it starts the Activity as desired. However when I press the back button to go to the `Fragment` containing the `RecyclerView` `onActivityResult` is never called.  I have passed in a context to the custom `RecyclerAdapter`.  Is this something that is possible? Or does the Activity/Fragment initiating `startActivityForResult` be the one that intercepts it? If not I will end up handling the onClick in the Fragment with a gesture detector or something similar, but before that I wanted to give this a fair crack! Note: I have included `onActivityResult` in the `MainActivity` which has the `Fragment` container so the `Fragment` does receive `onActivityResult` if `startActivityForResult` is initiated from the `Fragment`.  My code:

RecyclerAdapter onClickListener:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String titleId = titlesListDataArrayList.get(getLayoutPosition()).getTitle_id();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CreateItemsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("TITLE_ID", titleId);
            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.NEW_ITEMS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
```

CreateItemsActivity.class - onBackPressed()

```
    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(Constants.NEW_ITEMS_REQUEST_CODE, intent);
            finish();
        }
```

MyListsFragment.class (contains RecyclerView)

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.e("CALLED", "OnActivity Result");

        // if requestCode matches from CreateItemsActivity
        if (requestCode == Constants.NEW_ITEMS_REQUEST_CODE) {

            Log.e("REQUEST CODE", String.valueOf(requestCode));

            populateRecyclerView();
        }
    }
```

Also I have this in the MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // included to allow fragment to receive onActivityResult

    }
```

Comment: you need send `onActivityResult` directly to `MyListsFragment` from parent of `MyListsFragment` (activity)

Comment: I have edited question as I think it what you mean.

Comment: almost done:) add `fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);` in body of method after `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` when `fragment` is an instance of `MyListsFragment`

Comment: Hi,  many thanks - this does indeed work :) however whenever I try and execute the method populateRecyclerView(); I get NullPointerException - I'm assuming this is because I added:  MyListsFragment fragment = new MyListsFragment();
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Comment: ok - sorted it - I now understood what you meant - I've included the solution - many thanks for your help +1 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so IF by any chance somebody else has this problem here is my

solution. I added this code into the MainActivity onActivityResult (note I have a frame container which is where all fragments are inflated):

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // get current fragment in container
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameContainer);
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

I believe this works as the MainActivity is top in the hierarchy and intercepts the onActivityResult, so basically I just point it where I want it to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Your calling Activities `onActivityResult` will only be called when the second activity finishes and a `setResult` has been executed.

Since the user is hitting the back button the 2nd activity is finishing without `setResult` being called.

You'll need to override `onBackPressed` so you can execute your `setResult` code.

I see you have implemented this but I think the crux of the issue is that you need to return `Activity.RESULT_OK` **not** your request code.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {       
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

In this case you don't need to explicitly return your `requestCode` of `Constants.NEW_ITEMS_REQUEST_CODE` because Android will forward that automatically.

Comment: Hi thanks for your advice - I have tried this however it is still not called.  I already have onActivityResult being called correctly using my onBackPressed() methos code. I use it in another instance from the first Fragment (not RecyclerAdapter)  so i know that onActivityResult is being called when initiated from the first Fragment using startActivityForResult.  I just can't get it to work inside the adapter. I think its because its not the initiating fragment, even though I have passed a context.