# onActivityResult never called in my nested fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I have many nested fragments.

- Activity A

  - MainFragment (in a FrameLayout)

    - Fragment A (in a FrameLayout in MainFragment)
    - Fragment B (in a FrameLayout in MainFragment)

      - Fragment C (in a ViewPager in Fragment B)
      - Fragment D (in a ViewPager in Fragment B) <--- this is where I want to catch onActivityResult

This is how I start activity for result:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Title"), FILE_PICK);
```

I don't have `onActivityResult` overriden anywhere else. I tried to call it in Activity A and it got called, but then even though I called super, it never came to Fragment D. Also tried to call `onActivityResult` in `MainFragment` and it never gets called there either.

Comment: This should be able to help you out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31012323/4252352 you may find you have to call `getChildFragmentManager()` as its nested fragment

Comment: http://blog.shamanland.com/2014/01/nested-fragments-for-result.html not sure if this is still up-to-date, or it was fixed. However this may be the case, i guess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The event is going to be received in the activity. To have it in Fragment D you have to propagate it.

On your parent activity override `onActivityResult` and start calling the `onActivityResult` of your fragments:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
    if(fragments != null){
        for(Fragment fragment : fragments){
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

In your parent fragment you have to do the same thing, but remember to use `getChildFragmentManager` to get the fragment manager of the fragment

```
    List <Fragment> fragments = getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
```

Comment: Thanks. I accepted this answer, because it is a "universal" solution to this problem. You simply call onActivityResult in all nested fragments. However I'd like to point out that @Jagu (below) also posted a very nice solution which solves this problem for a single fragment (exactly what I need).

Answer (score 4):

For calling onActivityResult on the FragmentD override onActivityResult in the parent activity like:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Fragment fragmentD = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_D_TAG");
        if (fragmentD != null) {
            fragmentD.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```